# How to reload page whitout breaking code?

Tags: jquery, dom

i have integrated in my system an external script to allow my users to receive credits after watched a video. After they clicked a link, a popup will load the video. After the video finished there is a callback "callback_on_conversion". I need to hide the button but it's not really easy. Reading the integration guide, i found:

> "This asynchronous behavior has a limitation: The javascript code that
>   you can run in these callback functions may not use the document.write
>   function as that will not work. Instead, we recommend that for
>   creating/inserting new elements (e.g. fallback AdTags) in the page you
>   use DOM and jQuery."

This is the actually script. Again, i don't know how to hide the "a" link when video finished.

```
       <script src="http://iframe.sponsorpay.com/javascripts/widget/v1/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var sp_object = new SPONSORPAY.Video.Iframe({
            api_host: 'iframe.sponsorpay.com',
            asset_host: 'iframe.sponsorpay.com',
            appid: 'xxxx',
            uid: 'demouser',
            width: '750',
            height: '750',
            display_format: 'bare_player',
            callback_on_start: function() { alert('Video Ready'); },
            callback_on_conversion: function() { alert('finished'); },
            callback_no_offers: function() { alert('No video avabile.'); }
        });

        sp_object.backgroundLoad();
</script>

<a href="#" id="showvideo" name="showvideo" class="showvideo" onClick="sp_object.showVideo()">Load</a>
```

What should i do to prevent code breaking? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has LOTS of functions to manipulate the DOM tree. For instance, this selects the attribute with ID = 'showvideo' and removes it.

```
$('a#showvideo').remove();
```

Note that if there's more than 1 such element, only the first will be taken, but you can also select using a class:

```
$('a.showvideo').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

If `callback_on_conversion` is called when the video finishes you could simply hide it with jquery. http://api.jquery.com/hide/

```
callback_on_conversion: function() {
    $("a#showvideo").hide();
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukad, but even if i insert <script type="text/javascript">
$("a #showvideo").hide();
</script> after the "a" html, it won't work...

Comment: It should work if you define it like it did in your initialization of `sp_object`.
By the way, you have jquery installed, do you?

Comment: The problem here is the space between `a` and `#`. Because of the space, this reads as 'select all elements with an id of showvideo that are INSIDE a `<A>` element'. It's like CSS (but jQuery has way more options).

Comment: Yeah you're right. That's my fault. Didn't think of that. I'm fairly new to Javascript/Jquery.